# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Test' does not exist in the namespace 'SimpleDBAccess.Models'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm absolutely new at ASP.NET and MVC and so on. I'm trying to list in a web page the content of a SQL server database. In that way, i've created a simple MVC4 project with the followinf Index.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SimpleDBAccess.Models.MyDBModel>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Models folder, i've a MyDBModel.edmx file with the right database. And I've also created a controller :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SimpleDBAccess.Models;

namespace SimpleDBAccess.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private MyEntities _db = new MyEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.ISALLOCATEDTO.ToList()); //ISALLoCATEDTO : the table to list
        }
...
}
```

I've read a lot of things about the error I have but nothing seems to work :

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MyDBModel' does not exist in the namespace 'SimpleDBAccess.Models'
```

To my mind, it's a "path" failure : do I have to configure something in the Web.config file or something like that ? Once again, I'm a newbie...
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have a data model tied to the edmx file, i.e., MyDBModel.cs? Since 'MyDBModel' appears in the error, it would helpful to see what you if there, **if you have it at all**. ;)

Comment: Ok, the answer was quiet stupid : I just had to generate once again the solution and to create again the Index.aspx file (properly linked with the controller) and... Magical !